# Google Calendar API: writer access error when setting up Google calendar event create on Google business account

Tags: angular, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API in my Angular 9 Web Application and  trying to create events on a Google Calendar within my G Suite domain

In the G Suite Admin Console, I've given the service account permissions for the scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

I created the calendar itself under my account and have added the service account with "Make changes to events" permissions

NOTE: I tried the normal gmail account. It is working. But when I try the google business account, I have above problem(Like writer access error when setting up Google calendar event create).

I am using this code for saving a calendar event:

Please find below Screen Shot.

```js
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    null,
    GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
);
const calendar = google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    project: GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER,
    auth: jwtClient
});
var appointment_data = {
    summary: 'xyz',
    location: 'Location info',
    description: 'Some description',
    start: {
        'dateTime': dataObj.appt_startdate_time,
        'timeZone': dataObj.appt_timeZone,
    },
    end: {
        'dateTime': dataObj.appt_enddate_time,
        'timeZone': dataObj.appt_timeZone,
    },
    attendees: [
        {
            "displayName": 'Xyz',
            "email": 'xyz@gmail.com'
        }
    ]
}
calendar.events.insert({
    calendarId: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
    resource: appointment_data,
}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
        return;
    }
})
```

[image: oo]

Comment: Please add the code you are using to create the events and authenticating the service account.

Comment: const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    null,
    GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
);
const calendar = google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    project: GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER,
    auth: jwtClient
});

Comment: var appointment_data = {
    summary: 'xyz',
    location: 'Location info',
    description: 'Some description',
    start: {
        'dateTime': dataObj.appt_startdate_time,
        'timeZone': dataObj.appt_timeZone,
    },
    end: {
        'dateTime': dataObj.appt_enddate_time,
        'timeZone': dataObj.appt_timeZone,
    },
    attendees: [
        {
            "displayName": 'Xyz',
            "email": 'xyz@gmail.com'
        }
    ]
}

Comment: calendar.events.insert({
    calendarId: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
    resource: appointment_data,
}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
        return;
    }
})

Comment: Please add it in the question. The comments are really hard to read and understand. Thank you

Comment: Just now i added into the question, Thank you.

Comment: Are you setting domain-wide delegation of authority for your service account?

Comment: Yes, I am enabled Domain-wide delegation setting.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You are **not** adding the impersonating email address to the `JWT` constructor method.

### Proposed modification

You'll have to add the email address of your domain user you would like to impersonate while creating the events:

```js
var key = require('/path/to/service-account-credentials.json');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'];

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    SCOPES,
    'impersonating-email-address' // Add this parameter
);
```

Now if you followed correctly these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) it should work perfectly.

### References

[Calendary API Service Accounts](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1574)

Comment: Hi Alessandro, where i can get "impersonating-email-address". Could you please help me out.

Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: FYI, In my business account i am unable to select "Make changes to events" option. in Share with Specific People Prompt. But the option Enabled in Normal Gmail accounts.

Comment: Its resolved now i followed this link : https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/605495?hl=en

Comment: when I add the "impersonating-email-address" I get an error `Error: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`